# command in Cygwin to bring cygwin window to front

Tags: cygwin

Is there a command in cygwin terminal that when it's executed, the cygwin window is bring to the top/front? (To notify user that the job it's running is done)

Answer (score 2):

First, iconify (`ESC[2t`) the window and then de-iconify (`ESC[1t`) it directly.
This brings the window in front of all other windows.

```
echo -e "\e[2t\e[1t"
```

Btw. I tested first with `ESC[5t` (*Raise the xterm window to the front of the stacking order*)
But this doesn't work as expected, as it only brings the window to the front of all mintty windows.